# Does Count(Distinct(*)) returns the distinct no of records in a table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, count, distinct

What is the difference between the below codes.

```
Select count(distinct(*)) from TableName;

Select count(*) from (Select distinct(*) from TableName;
```

I am running this code on azure Databricks and getting different values after executing both the codes. I am not sure why is this happening. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are those queries executed at all? I never used apache-spark or azure Databricks, but usually, you can't do distinct without providing a column name. So I have a table "rep" with a column "id" and when I execute select count(distinct id) from rep; and select count(*) from (select distinct(id) from rep);, the number of entries is the same.

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error here. However, count distinct means number of values when duplicates have been removed. A, A, A, B has two distinct values, A and B.

Comment: Yeah, they are getting executed successfully. They are not giving any syntax error. These two codes are just giving different results which I was not expecting

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, so the parentheses are completely superfluous. So, what you have is: `select count(distinct *) from tablename;` and `select count(*) from (select distinct * from tablename);`. But I agree with you that both queries should result in the same number. Probably the number of rows in the table. Or are there really duplicates in the table? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

The Databricks documentation is not clear on `count(distinct *)`. but it seems  that `count(distinct *)` removes the null and then count the rows whereas `count(*)` counts all the rows. https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/count.html

> If * is specified also counts row containing NULL values.

> If expr are specified counts only rows for which all expr are not NULL.

> If DISTINCT duplicate rows are not counted.

hence in your first query it skips the null values and in the second query it counts every row